# How can i unckeck all the selected check boxes, uncheck radio buttons, clear marked text fields after clicking reset button?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-button

I made a quiz application in android and after the user clicks on reset button i want all the marked answers to be unmarked or the app becomes same as when it started. How can i do so?

The code for XML and JAVA are present in the following github repository.
[Code:](https://github.com/raghavddps2/CurrentAffairsApplication/tree/master)

Here is a screenshot of the application. I want the app to be like starting when i click on the RESET button.
[image: Screenshot:]

Comment: get all the radioButton's instances & simply fire, radioButton.setChecked(false);

Comment: Since there is probably a `RecyclerView` you could simply send again the initial data to the adapter and call ` notifyDataSetChanged();`

Comment: @DarShan I didn't get it, can you please explain in a bit more detail! Thanks in advance.

Comment: or, giving an intent to the main-Activity will work right?

Comment: @RaghavMaheshwari the first thing is that you should use RecyclerView... coming back to the point, make all the RadioButtons private class level variables, initialise them in your Activity's onCreate() then in the onClick() of Reset Button, simple do .setChecked(false) on all RadioButtons

Comment: @DarShan not even close to a good approach... You are asking him to call manually `isChecked()` for ALL his radio buttons... What if I have 200 RadioButtons ? Will you create 200 radio buttons variables and call them all ? Holy..

Comment: @IonutJ.Bejan the answer is based on his applied approach, already told him that, not my fault 

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, after I read your source code from [here](https://github.com/raghavddps2/CurrentAffairsApplication/blob/master/MainActivity.java) I decided I shouldn't let you go on with that approach at all.

Take some time, and read a little bit about [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView) and how it works, it will make your life way easier.

[Here](https://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/) is a tutorial on how to use it in a sample.

Once you get familiarized with it, I am sure you will make that screen look better and also the code will be much much more clear and well written.

I could come with an approach for your particular case, but then you will copy paster it and that's it. Take some time, you'll like what you'll learn <3 
If is really needed I will edit the answer with a simple implementation.

Happy coding <3

Answer (score 1):

```
//you can use this on reset button click for  checkbox
if (checkBox1.isChecked()) {
             checkBox1.setChecked(false);
         }
if (checkBox2.isChecked()) {
             checkBox2.setChecked(false);
         }
```

Answer (score 1):

Pull all your checkbox in an Arraylist:

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> checkboxList = new ArrayList<>();
checkboxList.add(checkbox1);
```

Then to remove all checkbox with check, try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < checkboxList.size(); i++) {
   CheckBox checkBox = checkboxList.get(i);
   checkBox.setChecked(false);
}
```

I suggest you to use recyclerview because your code is not the best approach. Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 1):

In your MainActivity's onCreate(...) method add this:

```
Button resetButton=findViewById(R.id.button2);
resetButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            recreate();
        }
    });
```

It will call onDestroy() and restarts your Activity.
Hope I could help!
Regards,
Cs